Some problems about inet and osg when using omnet++
I'm trying to simulate nesting network at omnet++.
After i import the nesting project and inet into the omnet++, i build the project and i encounter some problems like below:
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::AutoTransform::setNormal(osg::Vec3f const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::Texture::setFilter(osg::Texture::FilterParameter, osg::Texture::FilterMode)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::NodeVisitor::apply(osg::Node&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `vtable for osg::Array'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osgEarth::GeoTransform::GeoTransform()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for osg::Group'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::Shader::Shader(osg::Shader::Type)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::NodeVisitor::apply(osg::ProxyNode&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::Node::getOrCreateStateSet()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::Texture2D::Texture2D()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::NodeVisitor::apply(osg::OcclusionQueryNode&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::StateSet::setMode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::BufferData::~BufferData()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::StateSet::getAttribute(osg::StateAttribute::Type, unsigned int)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for osg::NodeVisitor'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osgText::TextBase::setDrawMode(unsigned int)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::Transform::Transform(osg::Transform const&, osg::CopyOp const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::Object::Object(osg::Object const&, osg::CopyOp const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `vtable for osg::DrawArrays'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::Referenced::Referenced(bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `vtable for osg::Box'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `osg::StateSet::setAttribute(osg::StateAttribute*, unsigned int)'
...

I just paste little of the errors. There still remains a lot and they just like these errors.
The versions:
omnet++: 5.5.1
inet: 4.1.2
os: Ubuntu20.04 Virtual Machine
I have tried to work on different os, such as Windows11, Wsl and Ubuntu20.4. And i still cannot solve it..
I searched one same problem but it still cannot help me, because i dont know how to diable osg and i didn't find the way now.

How about trying opp_env shell --install nesting-latest ?
